# yocto recipe for simple example using pybind11

Tags: yocto, pybind11, recipe

The example code I am using is this: https://github.com/pybind/python_example

I want to use this in Yocto Linux. I have a very basic idea about Yocto.
I have added `python3-pybind11` package into `IMAGE_INSTALL` and I checked if it is in the target:

```
root@qemuarm64:~# python3
Python 3.8.18 (default, Aug 24 2023, 19:48:18) 
[GCC 9.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pybind11
>>> pybind11.__version__
'2.4.3'
```

The version is a bit old. Anyway I have changed `pyproject.toml` by lowering the version in the example:

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=42",
    "pybind11>=2.4.0", # << changed this
]
...
```

With this change, I still can build and run the example locally.

I created this recipe by `devtool add`:

```
SUMMARY = "A test project using pybind11"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/pybind/python_example"
LICENSE = "Unknown"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=153b3e05cd731791777324af9f7219b3"

SRC_URI = "git://git@gitlab.com/sharedlib/python-example-pybind.git;protocol=ssh;branch=master"

PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "e2350ed9dad1c5b424f840c21079d51976463e41"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit setuptools3

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "python3-pybind11"

FILES_${PN} += "/usr/lib/"
```

I have no idea how I need to change this.
And I got this error:

```
ERROR: python-example-1.0+git999-r0 do_compile: 'python3 setup.py build ' execution failed.
ERROR: python-example-1.0+git999-r0 do_compile: Execution of '/workspaces/devcontainer-do/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python-example/1.0+git999-r0/temp/run.do_compile.701172' failed with exit code 1
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /workspaces/devcontainer-do/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python-example/1.0+git999-r0/temp/log.do_compile.701172
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function externalsrc_compile_prefunc
| NOTE: python-example: compiling from external source tree /workspaces/devcontainer-do/build/workspace/sources/python-example
| DEBUG: Python function externalsrc_compile_prefunc finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
|     from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension, build_ext
| ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pybind11'
| ERROR: 'python3 setup.py build ' execution failed.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
```

Can you help me?

Comment: First, double check where you are getting that old pybind from -- is your yocto _really_ that old or are you using meta-python2 by accident? Second, you are going to need a build dependency on pybind as your build (setup.py) requires it. `DEPENDS = "python3-pybind11-native"` might help but your best bet might be to find a recipe that uses pybind already and copy what they do

Comment: Also your local build test doesn't actually prove that the example works with the old version: you need to actually install pybind11 2.4.3 and then build locally